# Files and HTTPS on Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I'm hosting files on Parse and was wondering how to get an HTTPS link for uploaded files/images, as opposed to HTTP. I'm creating a web app and without all the assets being sent over SSL, it has the potential to throw errors and not appear on certain browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your uploaded file stored in any class and the column name is

profilePic then you can use

```
profilePic._url
```

for getting https link or url of it..